# Unable to switch database via clickhouse jdbc

Tags: sql, jdbc, clickhouse

I'd like to switch database in clickhouse jdbc, but fails with the following error. Does clickhouse jdbc not support switching database ?

```
USE DATABASE test_db
```

- 

```
ClickHouse exception, code: 62, host: 192.168.0.4, port: 8123; Code: 62, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 5 ('DATABASE'): DATABASE test_db. Expected identifier (version 20.8.12.2)
```

Comment: and you need a session enabled.  JDBC parameter session_ID=any_string

Answer (score 1):

See [USE](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/use/) statement info.

```sql
USE test_db
```

---

This won't work for HTTP - see docs:

> This query can’t be made when using the HTTP protocol, since there is
> no concept of a session.

Follow this way to define [default database](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/#default-database) when used HTTP:

```sh
echo 'SELECT number FROM numbers LIMIT 10' /
  | curl 'http://localhost:8123/?database=system' --data-binary @-
```

---

It looks like need to define database in the connection string of [clickhouse-jdbc-driver](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc#clickhouse-jdbc-driver):

```sh
jdbc:clickhouse://<host>:<port>[/<database>]
```

Comment: I will get the following exception：ClickHouse exception, code: 113, host: 192.168.0.4, port: 8123; Code: 113, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: There is no session (version 20.8.12.2)

Comment: @zjffdu it is correct behavior; I extended my answer to cover HTTP use case.

Comment: I didn't use http, I use jdbc, do you mean clickhouse jdbc use http protocol ?

Comment: All right, but it seems very inconvenience especially user are using some BI tools to query clickhouse.

Comment: @zjffdu Is it BI tools don't provide the ability to choose specific DB in UI when are reports preparing? Which BI tools do you use?

Comment: I use zeppelin to connect to clickhouse, I also use hive/spark/flink in zeppelin as well. All of them support to switch database via sql (even can creating/deleting database via sql)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setCatalog` method to change the current database in JDBC

https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/blob/master/clickhouse-jdbc/src/main/java/ru/yandex/clickhouse/ClickHouseConnectionImpl.java#L267

Comment: Is it possible to do in sql ? something like: use catalog <catalog_name>